# Trouble with SPF and Return-Path Headers in Postfix Email Setup

Tags: email, postfix-mta, spf

I'm facing an issue with sending emails using my Postfix MTA (sender.domain.com) and could use some guidance. My goal is to send emails from myname@domain.com. However, I'm encountering SPF-related problems and inconsistencies in how email clients display the sender's address.

Here's the detailed scenario:
When I connect to my MTA on port 25 and set the following headers:

From: myname@domain.com
Return-Path: Bounces+blablabla+myname@sender.domain.com

The email fails due to SPF checks as sender.domain.com isn't included in the SPF records. Additionally, the Return-Path header seems to disappear by the time the email reaches its final destination.

But if I change and send this headers:
From: myname@domain.com
Return-Path: Bounces+blablabla+myname@sender.domain.com
Sender: Bounces+blablabla+myname@sender.domain.com

SPF checks pass since sender.domain.com is included in the SPF records. However, some email clients display the From address as Bounces+blablabla+myname@sender.domain.com, while others display it correctly as myname@domain.com.

My Questions:

What could be causing the Return-Path header to disappear in the initial setup?
Why do some email clients display the From address differently in the modified setup?
Is there a way to configure my Postfix setup so that SPF checks pass without affecting the display of the From address in various email clients?

Comment: When you state that "the email fails", what do you mean exactly? Can you share some email headers, or other evidence to show how the email fails? And what is in your code when you try to send those emails? Even if you fixed the issue, it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

As a sender, it's not up to you to set a return-path; that's the receiver's job. Setting it when sending is an RFC contravention. The address it uses is obtained from the SMTP `MAIL FROM` address, not within the message. It's likely that the address you're putting in the message is being replaced with the `MAIL FROM` address that the server is configured to use.

The right solution to this is to not set the return-path yourself, add the MAIL FROM domain to your SPF, and to use DMARC to validate the From address in your message. You may notice that it's tricky to get DMARC alignment right when you are sending through third parties, and you have my sympathies... That can be solved with subdomains and CNAMEs, but it's not pretty.

Mail clients should not usually display the return path unless you explicitly show headers.

Comment: In my case, dkim is not a problem works pretty well with different selectors. My problem is spf, If I add the sender mta to the spf I have no problem, but I want to isolate each server in one spf to avoid that one modification could compromise others. In my installation, if I set only envelop (mail from) without return-path or sender, that information disappears and spf fails.

Comment: After lot of tests I got the conclusion that my library, go mail, was doing something won't. Now I'm building the email by my own and it's work as expected. I don't know if I must close the thread

Comment: @synchro When connecting on port 25 to an MTA, I don't see how it would be against RFC to set the Return-Path (bounce address) for a specific email. Can you specify which RFC and which part it violates?

Comment: The `Sender` header is used to signal that a specific address (Sender) is sending on behalf of another address (`From`). Email clients often show a `via` or `on behalf of` part in the FROM section of an email, when the `Sender` header differs from the `From` address. SPF is checked on the Return-Path address, which is usually not visible in email clients, unless headers are inspected. This is why DMARC is relevant for spoof protection. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2076#section-3.4 on the different headers and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.4 for the Return-Path usage

Comment: To quote from that same section of the later RFC5321: "A message-originating SMTP system SHOULD NOT send a message that already contains a Return-path header."

Comment: You are correct. I reread your answer, and indeed it states exactly that.